How to assign a dynamic numeric group Id on a table rows base on their groups in MySql?
I have a table like this:



Name
family
group
Age
id




test1
test1
gr_one
23
1


test2
test2
gr_one
28
2


test3
test3
gr_two
24
3


test4
test4
gr_three
30
4


test5
test5
gr_three
35
5



I need a query to create a result like this:



group
dynamic_id




gr_one
1


gr_two
2


gr_three
3



I am using Mysql version 5.7 so It seems Windowed functions are not supported.

Obtain distinct group values in the subquery then enumerate them. Use user-defined variable.

You should upgrade to MySQL 8.0 or later. MySQL 5.7 is past its end of support since November 2023.

SELECT `group`, @id := @id + 1 dynamic_id
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT `group` FROM tablename) groups
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @id := 0 ) variable;

You may add ORDER BY which will define the rows enumeration order if needed.
